# Combine two values with ternary operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements, conditional-operator, ternary

Having the following code snippet:

```
const value1 = isSomething ? 'a' : isSomethingElse ? 'b' : 'c';
const value2 = isSomething ? 1 : isSomethingElse ? 2 : 3;
```

Those two variables are depending of the same other variables behavior (`isSomething` and `isSomethingElse`)

Is there a way to write this code into a single line?

Comment: Are you trying to be deliberately cryptic? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @isherwood I'm trying to write less code

Comment: You may achieve that, but with much more time spent. Also, the next developer to come along will not appreciate it much.

Comment: destructuring isn't necesarrily more cryptic, and it reduces repetition, though if those two variables are always linked by conditions like that perhaps you should be declaring an object with properties.

Comment: With a regular if statement, it'd be less cryptic and less repetitive... and only a few extra characters. you aren't saving much.

Comment: It's good intuition to recognize there's repetition in this pattern. Take a look at the bigger picture of what `isSomething`, `'a'` and `1` represent, and how they are related to one another. It's likely you can find an object model that better represents your intention, and the code then becomes more readable and less repetitive as a side effect (e.g. `const activeThing = things.find(t => t.isActive); const [value1, value2] = [activeThing.value1, activeThing.value2]`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays, and destructuring assignment, but it will not be faster:

```
const [value1, value2] = isSomething ? ['a', 1] 
                       : isSomethingElse ? ['b', 2] : ['c', 3];
```